# How to use git for projects which has shared files

Tags: git, github

Our team uses shared folders (Windows) to work on projects together.
We never make local copies, but always edit the files in-place.
Now I've heard we would be much better off using git.
Is git a reasonable option is this case? And if so, how can we use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your situation today:

> Our team uses shared folders (Windows) to work on projects together. We never make local copies, but always edit the files in-place.

- One Source
- No versioning
- No chance to *even detect* what is called *merge conflicts*. What you play is »*last saved wins*« You have to put *social constraints* like »Okay, we agree never to edit the same file«. That is *weak*.

So in general *any VCS* (Version Control System) would be a benefit.

> Now I've heard we would be much better off using git. Is git a reasonable option is this case? And if so, how can we use it?

Yes, git is one choice, but there are others ([plastic-scm](https://www.plasticscm.com/home.html), [mercurial](https://mercurial.selenic.com/), [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/), [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/) to name some).

These are the main benefits for your current scenario (not everything is exclusive to git):

- git allows you *easily* to *branch off* something for development purposes
  Think of it as follows: git *remembers* (like *bookmarking*) where you were with your work at a certain point of time. And from there you could apply changes to that. If you successfully end your work, you could *merge* your work into the main *branch*. If you are unhappy, you could *revert* to *any previous state* or throw your *branch* away.
- as previously said, changes, which were branched off at some point, could be *merged together* at some time, conflicts will be shown.
- you have a history of *who* did *what* and *when* down to the *line of code*.
- since *branching* and *reverting* is easy, you could do more "experiments" on your codebase
- no *weak* social constraints to solve *merge conflicts*
- you could work *offline*

You may think about it.